# Lightning component error: Cannot find action on controller when it is there

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to build a lightning component and I am really lost as to why I am getting this component error when trying to load the component.

> Unable to find action 'getGType' on the controller of c:WLoanTerms

Here is the code I am using:

WLoanTerms.cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" controller ="LoanTest" >
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value ="{!this}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="loan" type="LLC_BI__Loan__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="gType" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="memo" type="Credit_Memo_R__c"/>
    
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="recordId" objectApiName="Credit_Memo_R__c">
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="{!v.loan.LLC_BI__Description__c}" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Current_Status__c" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Equity_Cash_Out__c" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!v.loan.LLC_BI__Amount__c}"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Amortization__c" readonly="true" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Interest_Type__c" readonly="true" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Interest_Rate_Spread__c" readonly="true" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!v.loan.cm_Sub_Loan__r.cm_Rate_Floor__c}" readonly="true"/>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!v.loan.cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Interest_Accrual_Method__c}" readonly="true"/>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
    
</aura:component>
```

WLoanTermsController.js:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.helperMethod(component);
       
        
        
    }
})
```

WLoanTermsHelper.js:

```
({
    helperMethod : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getLoan");
        var theid = component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({"memo" : theid});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.loan", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        
        var action2 = component.get("c.getGType");
        var theid = component.get("v.recordId");
        action2.setParams({"memo" : theid});
        action2.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.gType", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action2);
        
        var action3 = component.get("c.getMemo");
        var theid = component.get("v.recordId");
        action3.setParams({"memid" : theid});
        action3.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.memo", response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action3);
    }
})
```

LoanTest.apxc:

```
public class LoanTest {
    @AuraEnabled
    
    public static LLC_BI__Loan__c getLoan(String memo){
            System.debug('madeloan');
        Credit_Memo_R__c gotMemo = getMemo(memo);
        String loanst = gotMemo.Loan__c; 
        list<LLC_BI__Loan__c> allLoans = [select LLC_BI__Account__r.Name, 
                                          cm_Opportunity_Lookup__r.Owner.Name,  
                                          cm_Credit_Analyst_Underwriter__r.Name,    
                                          LLC_BI__Description__c,   LLC_BI__Amount__c,   
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Term_Months__c,    
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Interest_Only_Months__c,   
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Amortized_Term__c, 
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Pricing_Basis__c,  
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Index__c,  
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Spread__c, 
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__InterestRate__c,   
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.cm_Rate_Floor__c,  
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Interest_Accrual_Method__c,    
                                          LLC_BI__Product_Package__r.LLC_BI__Risk_Rating__c,    
                                          Application_Date__c, LLC_BI__CloseDate__c,    
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Maturity_Date__c,  
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.cm_Is_Payment_in_Kind__c,
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Prepayment_Penalty__c, 
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.LLC_BI__Prepayment_Penalty_Description__c, 
                                          LLC_BI__Total_Collateral_Value__c,    
                                          LLC_BI__Current_Total_Lendable_Value__c,  
                                          LLC_BI__Current_LTV__c,   
                                          LLC_BI__Account__r.cm_NAICS_Code__r.cm_NAICS_Code__c, 
                                          LLC_BI__Account__r.cm_NAICS_Code__r.cm_NAICS_Description__c,  
                                          HVCRE_Reportable__c,  LLC_BI__HMDA_Reportable__c,
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.Primary_Source_of_Repayment__c,    
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.Secondary_Source_of_Repayment__c,  
                                          cm_Sub_Loan__r.Tertiary_Source_of_Repayment__c,   
                                          id,   LLC_BI__Account__r.Account_ID_Long__c,  
                                          LLC_BI__Is_Main__c,   
                                          LLC_BI__Loan_Collateral_Aggregate__r.Id,  
                                          LLC_BI__Loan_Collateral_Aggregate__r.Name 
                                          from LLC_BI__Loan__c where id = :loanst];
        return allLoans.get(0);
    }
    
    public static Credit_Memo_R__c getMemo(String memid){
        list<Credit_Memo_R__c> memoList = [select Amortization__c,
                                           CreatedById,
                                           Name,
                                           Current_Status__c,
                                           Equity_Cash_Out__c,
                                           Interest_Rate_Spread__c,
                                           Interest_Type__c,
                                           LastModifiedById,
                                           Loan__c
                                           from Credit_Memo_R__c where id = :memid];
        Credit_Memo_R__c gotMemo = memoList.get(0);
        return gotMemo;
    }
    

    
    public static List<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> getGuarantors(String memo){
        System.debug('got g');
        LLC_BI__Loan__c loan = getLoan(memo);
        String loanid = loan.Id;
        list<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> out = [select LLC_BI__Borrower_Type__c, 
                                 LLC_BI__Account__r.Name,
                                 LLC_BI__Contingent_Type__c,    LLC_BI__Ownership__c,
                                 LLC_BI__Contingent_Amount__c,  LLC_BI__Guaranty_Amount__c,
                                 LLC_BI__Limited_Guaranty_Amount__c,    LLC_BI__Loan__r.Id,
                                 Id, LLC_BI__Account__r.Account_ID_Long__c
                                 from LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c where LLC_BI__Loan__r.Id = :loanid 
                                 and LLC_BI__Borrower_Type__c = 'Guarantor'
        ];
     return out;   
    }
    
    public static String getGType(String memo){
        List<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> gs = getGuarantors(memo);
        boolean move = true;
        for(Integer i = 0; i < gs.size(); i++){
            LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c thisg = gs.get(i);
            if(thisg.LLC_BI__Contingent_Type__c!='Joint & Several'){
                move = false;
            }
        }
        if(move){
            return 'Full Recorse';
                }else{
                    LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c thisg = gs.get(0);
                    if(thisg.LLC_BI__Contingent_Type__c == 'Joint & Several'){
                        return 'Partial Recourse';
                    }else{
                        return 'No Recourse';
                    }
                }
    }

}
```

I know that is a lot of code to go through, but I am so lost. Mainly because, as you can see getGType, is in a method in the controller. So I really don't know what could be causing this. Any help you can give would be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every method which is being referred from Aura or LWC component needs to be annotated with `@AuraEnabled`

I see you are missing that from `getGType` method in controller.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getGType(String memo){
    List<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> gs = getGuarantors(memo);
    boolean move = true;
    for(Integer i = 0; i < gs.size(); i++){
        LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c thisg = gs.get(i);
        if(thisg.LLC_BI__Contingent_Type__c!='Joint & Several'){
            move = false;
        }
    }
    if(move){
        return 'Full Recorse';
            }else{
                LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c thisg = gs.get(0);
                if(thisg.LLC_BI__Contingent_Type__c == 'Joint & Several'){
                    return 'Partial Recourse';
                }else{
                    return 'No Recourse';
                }
            }
}
```

You need to fix `getMemo` method too as shown above. As I see that also being referred in Aura Component.